# Spelling mistakes in my PDF file even if there are none in my code

Tags: pdf, spelling

A lot of words and sentences are mixed and wrongfully displayed when I build my PDF file even if I wrote them down correctly in my code... Here are pictures of a my code and the PDF that it generates:

Also, when I paste my code into my coworker's file, there are no problems, I've tried various version of various platform and I ended up having always the same problem.
In mine, it's written that I have 21 errors, however, when I paste the exact same code into the exact same platform of my coworker, again, there are no errors and no problems...
What could be the problem here?

Comment: Please edit and improve your question adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, tags of the programming lenguage or api you are using

Comment: I'm using texniccenter and my code is this :

Comment: it's just an exemple:

Comment: \begin{document}   
\thispagestyle{empty} % pas de header sur la première page
\begin{center}

\large PHY--1002 \textit{Physique mathématique II}
\hfill
\large \textsc{Mathieu Girard}\\
\large Travail présenté à Michèle \textsc{Desjardins}
\hfill
\large \textsc{David Tremblay} \\~\\
\Large \textbf{Devoir 1}  \\
\large \today
      
\end{center}